# 5*1 matrix of 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays

when i am working with 2d arrays.  i had given an input of 5*1 matrix and the it results like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int rows=5,cols=1;
int arr[rows][cols];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
printf("%d\n",arr[2][0]);
printf("%d\n",arr[0][2]);
return 0;
}
```

Input: `1 2 3 4 5`

Output :`3 3 3`

How thus it works?

Comment: Please turn the recenlty added part on different code into a separate question. Do not play the moving target game.

Comment: Please ask your continuation in another question. There are already several answers that address your original. It is not nice to change everything after 33 minutes.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the rollback. I considered, but felt it would look petty from one of the affected answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With (effectively)

```
int arr[5][1];
```

The only array members you can meaningfully access are

```
arr[0][0]
arr[1][0]
arr[2][0]
arr[3][0]
arr[4][0]
```

You might get lucky that your accesses

```
arr[r][c]
```

with c!=0 are treated as

```
arr[r+c]
```

but there is no guarantee.

You probably have intentionally designed your access to all be r+c==2.
And the value of arr[2] is 3.

Comment: but, I don't understand why it gives  **Error** : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while doing it in pointers

Comment: That is another question, on different code, which you kindly added after I have answered your question in its original state. That is called a moving target question. Please turn that part into a separate question. All the answerers will appreciate you staying fair towards people spending their time on helping you.

Comment: Sorry for that @Yunnosch I'm beginner here

Comment: It's OK, as long as you see the point. Good luck with the new question. I am sure that people will hurry to help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

Change below snippet

```
printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
printf("%d\n",arr[2][0]);
printf("%d\n",arr[0][2]);
```

to following one:

```
printf("%d\n",arr[1][0]);
printf("%d\n",arr[2][0]);
printf("%d\n",arr[0][0]);
```

As Yunnosch  mentioned in comment, you are trying to access outside of  array and observing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Here

`int arr[rows][cols];`

`cols` value is `1` means in each `arr[rows]` you can store only one elements as array index starts from `zero`. Hence `arr[1][1]` doesn't exists at all, there is only `arr[1][0]` exists.

Here in all `printf` statement you are accessing array elements out of bounds which invokes **undefined baheviour**.

`printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);/* result is UB, it may prints some junk data */`

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array subscript out of range is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`arr` is a `2D` array with dimension `5x1`. 
These statements

```
printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]); // UB --> accessing second row second column element
printf("%d\n",arr[2][0]); // Valid --> accessing third row first column elemnt
printf("%d\n",arr[0][2]); // UB --> accessing first row third column element
```

The in-memory view of 5x1 array would be something like this:

```
arr 5x1
        col 0
 row 0  +----+
 [0][0] |    |
        |    |
 row 1  +----+
 [1][0] |    |
        |    |
 row 2  +----+
 [2][0] |    |
        |    |
 row 3  +----+
 [3][0] |    |
        |    |
 row 4  +----+
 [4][0] |    |
        |    |
        +----+
```

In `5x1` array, the valid value of rows is from `0` to `4` and the only valid value of column is `0` (as you have only one column in your 2D array). Trying to access any value of `row` and `column` beyond these will lead to undefined behavior.